# add custom informations to ghost posts

Tags: node.js, ghost

I am searching an CMS to publish a blog based on nodejs. One of the cms I found was ghost. It looks easy. But I am not sure if it is to simple.

What I want to do is, to add Infomationens like a location or a city name, to show Post or Images on a Map. I found no informations about. Is it possible?

If not, are there other Blog systems base on nodejs which have possibilty to add custom information?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't built into the Ghost core, but you could write your own plugin to do this! Check out the development documents here https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Apps-Getting-Started-for-Ghost-Devs